# ReportParameter Exception Error

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

Hi I already developed a website with reporting function and it working without any problem. Now I want develop a Windows Form App and C# with reporting function. This is what I did:

```
private void print_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rptViewer.Reset();
        DataTable dt = getData("2");
        ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt);
        rptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
        rptViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"PAL\Report1.rdlc";
        ReportParameter[] rptParams = new ReportParameter[] {
        new ReportParameter("invoiceId","2")
        };
        rptViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(rptParams);
        rptViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
        this.rptViewer.RefreshReport();
    }
```

And another function for filling DataTable:

```
private DataTable getData(string id)
    {
        string[] dataName = new string[1];
        dataName[0] = "@invoiceId";
        string[] dataValue = new string[1];
        dataValue[0] = id;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = _cls.FillDataTable("procBasket", dataName, dataValue);
        return dt;
    }
```

But When I run the program, VS throw an error as like this:
[image]
and It seems VS can't found report path and throw below exception:

> Exception:Thrown: "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\BNS\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\nickSell\nickSell\bin\Debug\PAL\Report1.rdlc'." (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException)
>   A System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException was thrown: "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\BNS\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\nickSell\nickSell\bin\Debug\PAL\Report1.rdlc'."
>   Time: 2015/12/27 Sunday 7:53:53 PM
>   Thread:[10268]

I do something for path but error still is exists :(

```
string exeFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
string reportPath = Path.Combine(exeFolder, @"PAL\Report1.rdlc");
rptViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = reportPath;
```

at the end this is my solution tree view
[image] 

and print winform path that has reportview control is like this:
[image]

Comment: This is quite strange, did you check your `reportPath` (after modification) value in the debug mode? Does it really have value of the report path correctly?

Comment: the problem is VS wants read report file from debug folder but my report file is in solution folder. this is quite strange for me . I think I must change something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Application.StartUp` instead

Change this,

```
string exeFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

into

```
string exeFolder = Application.StartUp;
```

Edit: according to our [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99093/discussion-between-ian-and-blue-moon), the problem is that the report path is actually located in the parent of parent folder of the solution executable. That is why the error occurs.

In order to correct the error, simply go to the report folder by doing:

```
string dir = Directory.GetParent(Application.StartupPath).FullName; 
dir = Directory.GetParent(dir).FullName; //get parent of parent folder
string reportPath = Path.Combine(dir , @"PAL\Report1.rdlc"); //then do this
rptViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = reportPath;
```

This way, the report path points to the correct file in the correct folder. The key to solve this issue is **to get the folder right**.

Comment: I changed to `string exeFolder = Application.StartupPath;` but get same error :(

Comment: Ok, this is really strange. =( but did you check what is the `reportPath` string value?

Comment: this is the path after combining : `C:\\Users\\BNS\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\nickSell\\nickSell\\bin\\Debug\\PAL\\Report1.rdlc`. and this the physical path on my computer : `C:\Users\BNS\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\nickSell\nickSell\PALReport1.rdlc`.

Comment: Ok, and the actual report is not in the `nickSell\\nickSell\\bin\Debug\\`` etc..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99093/discussion-between-ian-and-blue-moon).